# Django annotate SUM of the field from ForeignKey model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I write code on Django and have a problem. I have 2 models.

```
class Statistic(models.Model):
    campaign_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    adgroup_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ad_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    campaign_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    adgroup_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ad_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date = models.DateField()
    spend = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0.0, )
    impressions = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    clicks = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    conversion = models.IntegerField(default=0)


class Tonic(models.Model):
    tiktok_statistic = models.ForeignKey(Statistic, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='tonic_statistic')
    campaign = models.ForeignKey(Campaigns, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(max_length=256)
    keyword = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    clicks = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    revenueUsd = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    id_campaign = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    id_adgroup = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    id_ad = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Also have 3 related model.

```
class Cross(models.Model):
tiktok_statistic = models.ForeignKey(Statistic, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True,
                                     related_name='cross_statistic')
campaign = models.ForeignKey(Campaign, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
date = models.DateField(max_length=256)
keyword = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
clicks = models.IntegerField(default=0)
revenue = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, default=0)
id_campaign = models.CharField(max_length=255)
id_adgroup = models.CharField(max_length=255)
id_ad = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I created endpoint in Rest Framework.

```
class StatisticViewSet(ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Statistic.objects.all().values('campaign_name').prefetch_related(
    'tonic_statistic').annotate(
        spend=Sum('spend'),
        impressions=Sum('impressions'),
        clicks=Sum('clicks'),
        conversions=Sum('conversion'),
        revenue_tonic=Sum('tonic_statistic__revenueUsd'),
        revenue_cross=Sum('cross_statistic__revenue')
    ).order_by('-spend')
```

When I annotated SUM of spend, impressions, clicks and conversions I got values that are 100-200 times greater than required. For example, the SPEND should be 4,000 and I get 900,000. I think this is because somehow values from related models are pulled up.

I can set distinct=True and then the values become close to correct, but in this case some data is lost.

Can you tell me how to fix it? Maybe I can set SPEND and other fields only from the current model, something like "self__spend"?

Comment: If you work with two JOINs, the two JOINs act as a multiplier of each other..

Comment: You you share how the `cross_statistic` looks like?